# Change UINavigationItem colour

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationbar

I need to set custom colors to my UINavigationBar buttons.
I'm doing the following thing(RGB func is a define):

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

for (UIView *view in self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews)      
    if ([[[view class] description] isEqualToString:@"UINavigationButton"])
        [(UINavigationButton *)view setTintColor:RGB(22.0,38.0,111.0)];

 }
```

Everything looks fine on app load. after leaving the view and getting back the color returns to default.

Secondly I need to set the same colour to UISegmentedControl to a pressed button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
[[theNavigationBar.subviews objectAtIndex:1] setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[theNavigationBar.subviews objectAtIndex:2] setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

However, HUGE, caveat. This is highly likely to break on a future OS release and is not recommended.

At the very least you should perform a lot of testing and make sure you your assumptions of the subview layout of the navigation bar are correct.
or
You can change the color by changing the tintColor property of the UINavigationBar

```
myBar.tintColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

or
You can follow the below link
  http://www.skylarcantu.com/blog/2009/11/05/changing-colors-of-uinavigationbarbuttons/

Answer (score 1):

[Change UINavigationItem colour](http://www.skylarcantu.com/blog/2009/11/05/changing-colors-of-uinavigationbarbuttons/"Changing colors of UINavigationBarButtons") and [to set same color to UISegmentControl](http://chris-software.com/index.php/tag/uisegmentedcontrol/) will help you to reach to your destination.

[**Here**](https://github.com/samvermette/SVSegmentedControl) is a sample code for to set color to UISegmentControl.

Answer (score 0):

For IOS5 will have to use ["setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:"](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html)

try this code to apply all UINavigationItem / UINavigationBar

```
 if([[UINavigationBar class] respondsToSelector:@selector(appearance)]){ //iOS >=5.0
    //use for UINavigationBar Custom image.
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageWithNamed:@"navImage.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    //use for UINavigationItem custom color
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
}
```

Comment: You are missing a closing square bracket for the line: //use for UINavigationItem custom color