# How to change the color of barButtonItem?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationbar

On a navigationBar as a rightBarButtonItem I take edit button by the following coding

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=self.editButtonItem;
```

but I want to change the color of edit button I mean I want to change the color of rightBarButtonItem.  How can I do this?

plz reply as early as possible.

thanx in advance.

Comment: You can refer my answer for this issue
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7314703/change-uinavigationitem-colour/7315008#7315008

Comment: Already solved problem here...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274473/how-to-tint-uibarbuttonitem-background-color/6157308#6157308)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to create a custom button and initialize your UIBarButtonItem using initWithCustomView.

Create your UIButton as you like if with your custom image and then:

```
UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:yourUIButton];
```

Answer (score 1):

You are constrained making standard UIBarButtonItem. But you can init it with any UIView of your choice, e.g. standard UIButton which you can color as you like.

```
UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
myButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 20); // change as you like being constrained with navigation bar hieght
[myButton setTitle:@"My Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Image for my button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; // <-- you can provide image instaed of title if you like
[myButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Background image for my button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; // <-- don't forget configure this!!! 
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:myButton];
```

Answer (score 0):

Visit this link. It is kind of same answer.

[specially indicating or highlighting a toolbar button when a note is added in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411506/specially-indicating-or-highlighting-a-toolbar-button-when-a-note-is-added-in-iph/7411843#7411843)

Usage of method `[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btnInfo];` can help.